# Rails running before_create for existing database record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a bunch of `character` models already in the database. Each `character has_one :iconfolio`. I migrated the database to add `icon_url` and `post_url` attributes to the `iconfolio` model, so I'm trying to update all `iconfolio` models in the database using the rails console.

However, setting the correct attributes for each existing record is non-trivial, so I've also added a `before_create` to `iconfolio` which will correctly set the `icon_url` and `post_url` attributes for new `characters` and `iconfolios`. But how do I force this code to execute for `characters` and `iconfolios` already in the database?

In the console I've tried:

```
Character.all.find_each do |char|
  char.create_iconfolio
end
```

but it doesn't update the database. It seems to delete the record:

```
(0.4ms)  COMMIT
Iconfolio Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "iconfolios".* FROM "iconfolios" WHERE "iconfolios"."character_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["character_id", 46]]
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "iconfolios" WHERE "iconfolios"."id" = $1  [["id", 46]]
```

I also tried:

```
Character.all.find_each do |char|
  Iconfolio.create(character_id: char.id)
end
```

This produced:

```
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
Character Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "characters".* FROM "characters" WHERE "characters"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "iconfolios" ("character_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "person_url", "followed_url", "icon_url", "post_url") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["character_id", 2], ["created_at", "2017-08-02 13:27:35.897842"], ["updated_at", "2017-08-02 13:27:35.897842"], ["person_url", "/assets/icon1.png"], ["followed_url", "/assets/icon2.png"], ["icon_url", "/assets/icon7.png"], ["post_url", "/assets/icon8.png"]]
(0.4ms)  COMMIT
```

which looks promising, but the database still not updated. (I've tried restarting the server etc).

What am I doing wrong?

**iconfolio.rb**

```
belongs_to :character

validates :character_id, presence: true

before_create do
  if self.character.type.is_a? User
    self.icon_url = '/assets/icon5.png'
    self.post_url = '/assets/icon6.png'
  else
    self.icon_url = '/assets/icon7.png'
    self.post_url = '/assets/icon8.png'
  end
end
```

Comment: The problem with ActiveRecord's `has_one` is that when you do `character.iconfolio`, it triggers a SQL query with a `LIMIT 1` clause. So you `character` record can actually have many `iconfolios` but the relation you defined (`has_one`) makes Rails select only one of them. If you do `Iconfolio.where(character_id: 2)` you will see several records (if you did not remove data inserted by your example) but `Character.find(2).iconfolio` will only return 1 of those records. In conclusion, `has_one` does not make sure you only have (max) 1 record associated, it just grab the first returned by the DB

Comment: It seems you did few mistakes in a row. One of them described by @MrYoshiji above, another - by MZaragoza in the answer.

Comment: If you want to update all existing records to follow the new DB structure, you should not use Rails console to do so (what if someday you forgot to do this manipulation after the `db:migrate`? Or if a migration created later uses this data to do extra logic? You can't stop the migration, run the code in the Rails console, and then redo the migration). If your DB structure changes and the current data needs to be updated, you have to do this in the very same migration file.

Comment: First of all, you have to create method like in MZaragoza's answer, then add some code in your migration right after column creation. The code should select existing `Iconfolio` and apply the methods for each one. Then run migration. There is an option to write faster update code in migration if condition as simple as in example provided in the question.

Answer (score 2):

What I like to do is move the before_create to a method

```
class Iconfolio
  belongs_to :character
  validates :character_id, presence: true
  before_create :set_attributes 

  def set_attributes
    if self.character.type.is_a? User
      self.icon_url = '/assets/icon5.png'
      self.post_url = '/assets/icon6.png'
    else
      self.icon_url = '/assets/icon7.png'
      self.post_url = '/assets/icon8.png'
    end
  end
end
```

now you can always call it when you need to

Answer (score 1):

As I commented on your question, you should not use Rails' console to update the existing Data to respect the new DB structure (I can provide examples why you should not do that if you need).

You should update this data in the very same migration that changes de DB structure:

```
# 1234_your_migration.rb
def up
  # changing the DB structure
  add_column :iconfolios, :icon_url, :string
  add_column :iconfolios, :post_url, :string

  # updating the current data
  Iconfolio.includes(:character).find_each do |iconfolio|
    if self.character.type.is_a? User
      self.icon_url = '/assets/icon5.png'
      self.post_url = '/assets/icon6.png'
    else
      self.icon_url = '/assets/icon7.png'
      self.post_url = '/assets/icon8.png'
    end
  end
end
```

This might be a heavy migration to run, depending on the quantity of Iconfolio records you have in the DB. You can do as shown here OR define a method `Iconfolio#update_icon_and_post_urls` but this method would be used only in the context of the Iconfolio creation OR in your migration, so that might be overkill, polluting your Iconfolio model in the long term and most importantly, can lead to problems when re-running migrations (see my comment on that answer).

Comment: With this example why not just do `  Iconfolio.includes(:character).find_each {|iconfolio| iconfolio.set_attributes }` This removes duplication in of code in the model and the migration?

Comment: @MZaragoza That is what I included in my answer but there is a flaw in this logic : if tomorrow we add a new URL to the Iconfolio model, and we update the `set_attributes` method accordingly, then when running the migration it will call the method which will try to set values for columns that does not exist (yet). That one of the many example of why a Rails DB migration should hold all the logic inside it and not call external methods. (to be honest, when we create a migration, we define the model's class in the Migration just in case someday the class is renamed)

Comment: I would agree. I can see that senario happening.